# makefile not putting the .o and executable in the respective obj and bin directories

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm new to c++ and make files. I'm currently trying to do a makefile with trial and error and I'm stuck. This is a copy of my makefile.

```
# SYNOPSIS:
#
#   make TARGET - makes the given target.
#   make clean  - removes all files generated by make.

# Please tweak the following variable definitions as needed by your
# project, except GTEST_HEADERS, which you can use in your own targets
# but shouldn't modify.

# Points to the root of Google Test, relative to where this file is.
GTEST_DIR = deps/googletest/googletest

# Points to the root of Pulse Waves, relative to where this file is.
PULSE_DIR = deps/PulseWaves

# Where to find user code.
USER_DIR =src

# Different directories
BIN=bin
OBJ=obj
LIB=lib

#Create directories if needed
$(BIN):
    mkdir $@
$(OBJ):
    mkdir $@
$(LIB):
    mkdir $@

# Flags passed to the preprocessor.
# Set Google Test's header directory as a system directory, such that
# the compiler doesn't generate warnings in Google Test headers.
CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include

# Flags passed to the C++ compiler.
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -I$(PULSE_DIR)/inc
CFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -I$(PULSE_DIR)/inc

# All tests produced by this Makefile.  Remember to add new tests you
# created to the list.
TESTS = $(BIN)/cmdLine_unittests $(BIN)/FullWaveformIngestion_unittests

# All Google Test headers.  Usually you shouldn't change this
# definition.
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/ \
                $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/


# Builds gtest.a and gtest_main.a.

# Usually you shouldn't tweak such internal variables, indicated by a
# trailing _.
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/ $(GTEST_DIR)/src/ $(GTEST_HEADERS)

# For simplicity and to avoid depending on Google Test's
# implementation details, the dependencies specified below are
# conservative and not optimized.  This is fine as Google Test
# compiles fast and for ordinary users its source rarely changes.
$(OBJ)/gtest-all.o : $(BIN) $(LIB) $(OBJ) $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc -o $@

$(OBJ)/gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc -o $@

$(LIB)/gtest.a : $(OBJ)/gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(LIB)/gtest_main.a : $(OBJ)/gtest-all.o $(OBJ)/gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

# Builds a test.  A test should link with either gtest.a or
# gtest_main.a, depending on whether it defines its own main()
# function.

$(BIN)/%_unittests:$(USER_DIR)/%_unittests.o $(USER_DIR)/%.o $(LIB)/gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@ -L$(PULSE_DIR)/lib -lpulsewaves

$(USER_DIR)/%_unittests.o: $(USER_DIR)/%_unittests.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^ 

$(USER_DIR)/FullWaveformIngestion.o: $(USER_DIR)/FullWaveformIngestion.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) -L$(PULSE_DIR)/lib

$(USER_DIR)/ScannerInformation.o: $(USER_DIR)/ScannerInformation.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) -L$(PULSE_DIR)/lib

$(USER_DIR)/%.o: $(USER_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

$(BIN)/lidarDriver: $(USER_DIR)/lidarDriver.o $(USER_DIR)/cmdLine.o $(USER_DIR)/ScannerInformation.o
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@ -L$(PULSE_DIR)/lib -lpulsewaves

.PHONY: test

lidarDriver: $(USER_DIR)/lidarDriver.o $(USER_DIR)/cmdLine.o $(USER_DIR)/parseFile.o $(USER_DIR)/ScannerInformation.o
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@ -L$(PULSE_DIR)/lib -lpulsewaves

test: $(TESTS)
    $(BIN)/cmdLine_unittests
    $(BIN)/FullWaveformIngestion_unittests

clean: 
    rm -f $(BIN)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*
    rm -f $(LIB)/*
    rm -f $(USER_DIR)/*.o
```

Everything else works the way its supposed to. I have other files that are being made in the corresponding directories.. However, I'm trying to put the lidarDriver.o in the obj directory and the lidarDriver executable in the bin directory. Can't figure out what I need to do.. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two rules that buld object files in `obj/`:

```
$(OBJ)/gtest-all.o : $(BIN) $(LIB) $(OBJ) $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc -o $@

$(OBJ)/gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc -o $@
```

Let's clean these up before we worry about building `obj/lidarDriver.o`.

The first rule has seven directories as prerequisites, the second has four. The correct number is one, `$(OBJ)` (which is missing from the second).

```
$(OBJ)/gtest-all.o : $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc -o $@

$(OBJ)/gtest_main.o : $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc -o $@
```

When a rule builds an object file from a source file, it makes sense to have that source file as a prerequisite of the rule (so that Make will rebuild the object when the source has been modified since the object was last built):

```
$(OBJ)/gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc -o $@

$(OBJ)/gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc -o $@
```

Now we can remove the redundancy by means of the [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$<`, which expands to the first member of the prerequisite list (just as `$@` expands to the name of the rule). This is not strictly necessary for your purposes, but it makes the rules cleaner.

```
$(OBJ)/gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

We could simplify even further, but that's for another day. Now you can add your rule for `obj/lidarDriver.o`:

```
$(OBJ)/lidarDriver.o : $(GTEST_DIR)/src/lidarDriver.cc $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Now a slight modification to the `$(BIN)/lidarDriver` rule:

```
$(BIN)/lidarDriver: $(OBJ)/lidarDriver.o ...
    ...
```

and we're done.